# Extrude along normals does not do what is expected

Tags: modeling, faces, extrude

I am following a tutorial and I am not able to do exactly what it is showing, when he extrudes the faces come out glued to each other but to me they come out individually separated with space between them.[image: Without extruding]
[image: How should it be extruded]
[image: How it comes out for me]

Comment: The Extrude operator has an 'Individual'  setting. Is that checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably unlikely, but one reason could be that the faces aren't connected to each other. If you press <kbd>m</kbd> and then choose *By Distance*, they should all be connected.

Comment: Not that unlikely, especially since the edges are marked sharp.

Comment: Yes, that is the solution, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help you because I don't use the language you use in your Blender, but make sure you don't confuse ✅ **"Extrude Faces Along Normals"** with ❌ *"Extrude Individual Faces"*

[image]